# Spark-submit Sql Context Create Statement does not work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

My below code does not work with Spark-submit.

```
sqlContext.sql(s"""
create external table if not exists landing (
date string,
referrer string)
partitioned by (partnerid string,dt string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 's3n://....'
      """)
```

It gives error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.2] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier create found

**This code works in Spark-shell but not in Spark-submit. What can be the reason?**

Comment: Maybe missing imports?

Comment: Also `import sqlContext.implicits._`?

Comment: class Analysis extends Serializable{
  val sc = new SparkContext()
  val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._ => I run it like this but no way :(

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

"sqlContext" in spark-shell is 'HiveContext' by default. Maybe you need to new a HiveContext instead of sqlContext in your script.

You may new it like that:

```
import SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._ 
val sc = new SparkContext()
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```